# Can there be multiple statements in the increment step of a for loop?

Tags: c, for-loop

Is it legal to have code with multiple statements in the increment step of a `for` loop, as shown here?

```
for ( ... ; ... ; q++, t += expression)
```

When I try this out, the expression `t += expression` seems not have been executed, but when I put `t += expression` in the for loop body, it works fine.

For reference, here's my code:

The code looks like this:

```
for(/* irrelevant */; /* ... */; q++, t -= p[q][t])
{ /* do some dp... */}

// t do not change when I print it out.
```

Second version:

```
for(/* irrelevant */; /* ... */; q++)
{ 
  /* do some dp... */
  t -= p[q][t];
}

// t updates this time
```

Comment: What does your actual code look like?

Comment: Appended above ... Have a look.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, the code

```
for (/* .. */; /* .. */; q++, t += expression)
```

Is legal and should execute the code `t += expression`.  This uses C's *comma operator*, a little-known operator that's pretty much used exclusively in this context.  The comma operator works such that writing

```
A, B;
```

Where `A` and `B` are expressions, evaluates both `A` and `B` in order and then yields the value of `B`.  So, for example, writing

```
int x = (1, 2);
```

Will give `x` the value `2`, since it's the last term in the comma expression.

In the context of this `for` loop, when writing

```
q++, t += expression
```

The code will execute `q++`, then execute `t += expression`, and then the entire expression evaluates to the new value of `t`.  However, since `for` loops discard the value of the third expression in the loop body, this value is not used anywhere.

Comment: THX. But I'm still a little puzzled for the code after comma should still be executed according to what you say. But I got t unchanged in my for loop...

Comment: @user616677- Without more information I don't think I can help you diagnose the problem.  All I know is that the statement will indeed be executed. Perhaps you're changing the value someplace else?

Answer (score 3):

The code in the third part of the for(;;) executes **after** the loop body. Is that the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The order of evaluation is inversed in your 2 examples

```
for(/* irrelevant */; /* ... */; q++, t -= p[q][t])
{ /* do some dp... */}

// t do not change when I print it out.
}
```

will execute `q++` before  `t -= p[q][t]` so the successor of `q` will be used in the index.

```
for(/* irrelevant */; /* ... */; q++)
{ 
   /* do some dp... */
   t -= p[q][t]; 
}
```

In this case `t -= p[q][t]` will be executed before `q++` the index q is not the same in your examples.

Your 2 expressions are not equivalent.